# Mocha test sync function which makes an async call

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to figure out how to test a synchronous method which makes an async call.

I have this method below, which I want to simply test and assert that `res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send()` returns a 200 response

```
'use strict'

const HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes')
let db = null

/**
 * Gets a resource by id
 * @param  {Object} req The request object
 * @param  {Object} res The response object
 * @return {Object}     An http response
 */
function getById (req, res) {
  const dockey = req.params.resourceType + '$' + req.params.id

  // The get by id query
  const query = ResourceTypesDao.getByIdQuery()

  db.transaction({
    write: ['auditevents', 'auditedges'],
    read: ['clindocs']
  },
  query,
  {
    key: dockey,
    id: req.params.id
  })
    .then(result => {
        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send()
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('err = ', err)
    })
}

module.exports = (database) => {
  db = database
  return getById
}
```

Corresponding spec file

```
'use strict'

const expect = require('chai').expect

let db = {
  transaction: function(collections, query, params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return resolve({doc: {}})
    })
  }
}

const getById = require('../../../src/controllers/resource-types/getById')(db)

let req = {
  params: {
    id: 'foo'
  }
}

let res = {
  status: function() {

    let self = {}

    function send() {

    }

    self.send = send
    return self
  },
  send: function() {

  }
}

describe.only('#getById', () => {

  it('should pass', (done) => {

const result = getById(req, res)
    setTimeout(() => {

      console.log('result = ', result) <-- returning undefined so this aint right
      expect(result).to.be.instanceOf(Object)
      done()
    }, 1000)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the promise from the `getById` function:

```
function getById (req, res) {
  ...
  return db.transaction({...}).then(...).catch(...);
}
```

Then in your test, wait for it to resolve before making an assertion:

```
it('should pass', (done) => {
  getById(req, res)
    .then(result => {
      // make assertion here
      done()
    });
});
```

Comment: That can be simplified, by returning the promise from the `it` callback instead of using the `done()` function. e.g. `return getbyId....`

Comment: True, but I prefer to rewrite as little as possible when answering questions so it's easy to understand the diff.

Comment: Since this is a function that is passed into an express route as the second parameter, e.g. `router.use('/', myFunction)` I can't just change the method to return a promise since it has to return some variant of a `response....send()` right?

Comment: You don't need to use `done` in Mocha. There's already a promise. Mocha uses promises. *prefer to rewrite as little as possible* - propagating mistakes done by the OP isn't a good practice. Failed assertion in `make assertion here` place will result in test timeout without a specific reason.

Comment: @Catfish Middleware/route return value is typically ignored, so you can use it for your own purpose, i.e. testability. `.catch(err => {
      console.log('err = ', err)
    })` is also a problem. An error is suppressed, you will just end up with pending request, also not straightforward to test. You would likely want `next(err)`, which is testable and suits the case better.